# Excision of topological open ball.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $B$ be a topological open ball (an open ball after a homeomorphism) in a Banach space $(X, ||\cdot||)$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane that cross the ball $B$.

How to prove or disprove that the connected components of $B \setminus H$ are topological balls?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not have to be topological balls. E.g. a bowl shape (with a finite wall thickness) is a topological sphere. However, you can cut through it in a way so that one half is now more like a topological torus.

[image]

Imagine cutting horizontally, removing the upper ring.

Comment: Dear M. Winter many thanks for your answer.